# Guzzle (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received over HTTP

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, guzzle, php-curl

I send an api request to other Server(http://example.com:8180) from my server
and I get this error

> "cURL error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed : An unexpected TLS packet was received."

The weird thing is that when I tested it in my local and stage server
There was no problem.
The difference between production and stage server is the existence of ssl.
But could It be the problem??

I kind of believe it's about "php curl" cuz guzzle doesn't work in code but curl on command does
and i used curl without guzzle in code but still didn't work.
and i set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` false
 but still didn't work.
and as long as I know SSL doens't matter cuz I try to connect to a server on HTTP right?

there's my compiled php, curl, the server info below

```
PHP Version => 7.2.1

System => Linux ip-x-x-x-x 4.4.0-1060-aws #69-Ubuntu SMP Sun May 20 13:42:07 UTC 2018 x86_64
Build Date => Jan 31 2019 05:39:24
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--enable-fpm' '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-libxml-dir' '--enable-intl' '--with-gettext' '--with-mhash' '--with-gd' '--with-pc
re-jit' '--with-zlib' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-zlib-dir' '--with-curl' '--enable-zip'

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.47.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => No
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => GnuTLS/3.4.10
ZLib Version => 1.2.8
```

---

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:8180
CONNECTED(00000003)
139662896404120:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1560955018
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.

I use laravel and There was a blackbox which is route() helper functiong
It sets the url http or https according to the server config
and the production server was set https

that's why it caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference to this error, which might help some one.
I was facing similar problem on my ubuntu machine with apache server which I solved by creating self signed certificate using [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04)

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connected
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 127 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 508 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

If you are using curl and facing below error, even after creating certificate and enabling that, You can use `--cacert <certificate name>` in your curl command.

error : `curl: (60) server certificate verification failed.`

try this : `curl --cacert <certificate_name>.crt https://<your IP>:<Port>`